# Label text rows according to lists of words

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, grepl

I have a dataframe where one column contains a number of short descriptions of policies. I also have a list that contains three sublists: 'private', 'public', and 'commercial'. These sublists contain a number of words that are associated with either private, public or commercial ev charging policies.

I need code that:

1. Checks if words from the lists are present in a text
2. a) If a word is present: take the name of the sublist and enter it in the column 'charging_type'

   b) If no word is present: leave empty

   c) If words from multiple sublists are present: take the names of all the sublists and enter it in the column 'charging_type'

The data (generated via `dput()`) looks like this:
The list of lists containing the dictionaries:

```r
list(private = list(c("income tax credit", "property owners", 
"homeowner", "owner", "personal use", "condominium", "common interest", 
"housing association", "tenant", "residential", "residents", 
"purchasers")), commercial = list(c("commercial", "fleet", "nonprofit", 
"non-residential", "industrial")), public = list(c("public", 
"utility-owned", "fast charging", "interstates", "highways", 
"network", "general public", "operators", "operator", "IOUs", 
"infrastructure", "disadvantaged communities", "charging station service providers", 
"low-income", "underserved")))
```

The dataframe with the text:

```r
structure(list(manual_classification = c("private", NA, "public", 
"public", "?", NA, "private", "public", "commercial", NA, "public", 
NA, NA, "private", NA), Text = c("a common interest development  including a community apartment \ncondominium  and cooperative development  may not prohibit or restrict\nthe installation or use of ev charging stations or ev dedicated\ntime of use  tou  meter in a homeowner s designated parking space or\nunit  these entities may put reasonable restrictions on ev charging\nstations  but the policies may not significantly increase the cost of\nthe ev charging stations or significantly decrease its efficiency or\nperformance  restrictions may be placed on tou meter installations if\nthey are based on the structure of or available space in the building \nif installation in the homeowner s designated parking space or unit is\nnot possible  with authorization  the homeowner may add ev charging\nstations or a ev dedicated tou meter in a common area  the homeowner\nmust obtain appropriate approvals from the common interest development\nassociation and agree in writing to comply with applicable architectural\nstandards  engage a licensed installation contractor  provide a\ncertificate of insurance  and pay for the electricity usage \nmaintenance  and other costs associated with the ev charging stations or\ntou meter  any application for approval should be processed by the\ncommon interest development association without willful avoidance or\ndelay  the homeowner and each successive homeowner of the parking space\nor unit equipped with ev charging stations or a tou meter is responsible\nfor the cost of the installation  maintenance  repair  removal  or\nreplacement of the equipment  as well as any resulting damage to the ev\ncharging stations  tou meter  or surrounding area  the homeowner must\nalso maintain a   1 million umbrella liability coverage policy and name\nthe common interest development as an additional insured entity under\nthe policy  if ev charging stations or an ev dedicated tou meter is\ninstalled in a common area for use by all members of the association \nthe common interest development must develop terms for use of the ev\ncharging stations or tou meter \n reference  california civil code 4745 and 6713  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
"the san joaquin valley air pollution control district  sjvapcd  and thesouth coast air quality management district  aqmd  administer enhancedfleet modernization program  efmp  pilot retire and replace programs providing incentives to replace a vehicle eligible for retirement with amore fuel efficient vehicle  used vehicles must be no more than eightyears old and applicants must live in the san joaquin valley or southcoast air basins  eligible replacement vehicles must meet a minimum fueleconomy average by model year or average at least 35 miles per gallon mpg   alternative fuel vehicles are also eligible  including plug inhybrid electric vehicles  phev  and battery electric vehicles  evs  funding for alternative transportation mobility options  such as publictransportation or car sharing  is also available in lieu of purchasinganother vehicle  the incentive amounts vary by income level as comparedto the federal poverty level  fpl  and replacement vehicle type  alleligible applicants must have a household income that is at or below400  of the fpl      data align  center    income eligibility                    fuel economy greater than 35 mpg   phev or zev                                                                                         low income    225  fpl                              4 500                    4 500  moderate income    300  fpl                         3 500                    3 500  above moderate income    400  fpl                   2 500                    2 500   residents living in qualified disadvantaged communities may be eligiblefor higher incentive amounts and  for residents replacing their vehicleswith a phev or ev  a rebate of up to   2 000 for the purchase ofelectric vehicle supply equipment  residents of south coast aqmd mayalso be eligible to receive a rebate of   7 500 for alternativetransportation mobility options  for more information  includingeligible vehicles and applicable requirements  see the california airresources board efmp  https   ww2 arb ca gov our work programs enhanced fleet modernization program  sjvapcd  driveclean  https   www valleyair org drivecleaninthesanjoaquin replace   and south coast aqmd  replace yourride  http   www replaceyourride com   websites  reference  california health and safety code 44062 3 and 44125  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
"municipalities may not restrict the types of evs  such as plug in hybridelectric vehicles  that may access an ev charging station that ispublic  intended for passenger vehicle use  and funded in any part bythe state or utility ratepayers  reference  california government code 65850 9  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
"the washington state department of ecology  ecology  will work with the\noffice of the governor and state agencies to select projects and\ndistribute funding to leverage 15  of washington  s portion of the  vw\nenvironmental mitigation\ntrust  https   www epa gov enforcement volkswagen clean air act civil settlement \nfor the acquisition  installation  operation  and maintenance of\nlight duty zero emission vehicle charging infrastructure \necology will establish a competitive process to identify and select\nprojects to fund with the remaining 85  of the appropriation to maximize\ntotal air pollution reduction and health benefits  improve air quality\nin areas disproportionately affected by air pollution  leverage\nadditional matching funds  achieve substantial emission reduction beyond\nwhat would occur absent the funding  accelerate fleet turnover to the\ncleanest engines  and accelerate adoption of electric vehicles \nequipment  and vessels  as appropriate  ecology will work with state\nagencies to select projects and distribute funding  for more\ninformation  see the ecology  vw enforcement\naction  https   ecology wa gov about us how we operate grants loans find a grant or loan volkswagen enforcement action grants \nwebsite \n", 
"an individual may not park a motor vehicle within any parking space\nspecifically designated for charging evs  to use the parking space  evs\nmust be actively charging  violators may receive a fine of up to   750 \n reference  nevada revised statutes 484b 468  https   www leg state nv us   ", 
"by january 1  2026  the kentucky finance and administration cabinet\n cabinet  must increase the use of ethanol  biodiesel  and other\nalternative transportation fuels and replace at least 50  of light duty\nstate fleet vehicles with new alternative fuel vehicles or vehicles\nequipped with low emission technology  beginning december 1  2024  the\ncabinet must compile annual reports detailing the progress made towards\nthese requirements  including a life cycle cost assessment  vehicle\nreplacement timeline  and targets for increased alternative fuels in\nstate agency vehicles \n\n reference  senate bill 281  2023  https   legislature ky gov legislation pages default aspx    26 u s  code 30b  http   www gpo gov fdsys    and  kentucky revised statutes 45a 625 and 152 715  http   lrc ky gov krs titles htm  ", 
"an income tax credit is available for 50  of the cost of alternative\nfueling infrastructure  up to   5 000  qualifying infrastructure\nincludes electric vehicle charging stations and equipment to dispense\nfuel that is 85  or more natural gas  propane  or hydrogen  unused\ncredits may be carried over into future tax years  for more information \nincluding how to claim the credit  please see the new york state\n department of taxation and\nfinance  http   www tax ny gov pit credits alt fuels elec vehicles htm \nwebsite   reference  new york tax\nlaw  http   public leginfo state ny us lawssrch cgi nvlwo   187 b ", 
"tva will establish and fund a network of direct current fast charging\n dcfc  stations every 50 miles along interstates and major highways\nthrough the fast charge network program  program   the program offers\nfunding for public dcfc stations along ev corridor gaps  up to   150 000\nper dcfc station  eligible applicants include tva local power companies \nand eligible projects must include a minimum of two dcfc ports per\nlocation  program participants must identify suitable host sites and\nagree to own  operate  and maintain program funded dcfc stations for a\nminimum of five years  for more information  including guidelines and\nadditional eligibility requirements  see the tva  fast charge\nnetwork  https   energyright com ev fast charger program   website \n", 
"pwp offers rebates of   3 000 per port for commercial  workplace multi unit dwelling  mud   and fleet customers for the installation ofnetworked level 2 ev charging stations  or rebates of   1 500 per portfor non networked level 2 ev charging stations  pwp also offers rebatesof   6 000 for the installation of direct current fast charging  dcfc stations or level 2 ev charging stations installed at select sites including disadvantaged communities  additional terms and conditionsapply  for more information  including how to apply  see the pwp commercial ev and charger incentiveprogram  https   ww5 cityofpasadena net water and power commercialchargerrebate  website ", 
"the u s  department of transportation s  dot   nevi formulaprogram  https   afdc energy gov laws 12744  requires the alabamadepartment of transportation  aldot   to submit an annual evinfrastructure deployment plan  plan  to the dot and u s  department ofenergy  doe   joint office of energy andtransportation  https   driveelectric gov   joint office   describinghow the state intends to distribute nevi funds  the submitted plans mustbe established according to  neviguidance  https   www fhwa dot gov environment alternative fuel corridors nominations 90d nevi formula program guidance pdf  for more information about alabama s nevi planning process  see thealabama department of economic and community affairs  electric vehiclecharging infrastructure program  https   adeca alabama gov ev   website to review alabama s nevi plan  see the joint office  state plans for evcharging  https   driveelectric gov state plans   website ", 
"at least one parking space  or 10  of parking spaces rounded to the next\nwhole number  must be made ready for level 2 ev charging stations at all\nnew buildings  electrical capacity must accommodate the potential to\nserve a minimum of 20  of the total parking spaces with level 2 ev\ncharging stations  for assembly  education  or mercantile buildings  the\nrequirements apply only to employee parking spaces  buildings classified\nas utility or miscellaneous and some residential buildings are exempt\nfrom these requirements  additional terms and conditions apply \n reference  revised code of washington 51 50 0429  https   apps leg wa gov rcw   ", 
"cities and counties that receive funding from the road maintenance andrehabilitation program are encouraged to use funds towards advancedtransportation technologies and communication systems  including  butnot limited to  zero emission vehicle fueling infrastructure andinfrastructure to vehicle communications for autonomous vehicles  reference  california streets and highways code 2030  http   leginfo legislature ca gov faces home xhtml  ", 
NA, "homeowners associations  hoas  or condominium associations may not\nprohibit the installation of an ev charging station for personal use\nwithin the ev charging station owner s designated parking space  hoas\nmay establish restrictions on the number  size  placement  manner of\ninstallation  and insurance requirements for the ev charging station if\nit is installed on the exterior of the property or in a common area \nhoas are not liable for the ev charging station \na condominium association may prohibit the installation of an ev\ncharging station if it is not technically feasible or practical due to\nsafety risks  structural issues  or engineering conditions  condominiums\nmay establish requirements on the manner of installation  architectural\ndesign  insurance requirements  and community related expenses for the\nev charging station \n reference  virginia code 55 1 1823 1  55 1 1962 1  and 55 1 2139 1  https   law lis virginia gov vacode   ", 
"new evs must be equipped with a conductive charger inlet port that meetsthe specifications contained in society of automotive engineers  sae standard j1772  evs must be equipped with an on board charger with aminimum output of 3 3 kilowatts  kw   these requirements do not apply toevs that are only capable of level 1 charging  which has a maximum powerof 12 amperes  amps   a branch circuit rating of 15 amps  and continuouspower of 1 44 kw  reference  california code of regulations title 13  section 1962 2  http   www oal ca gov   "
), charging_type = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want the column `charging_type` to be automatically classified according to the words in the lists.
So far I tried this approach:

```r
find_max_matching_list <- function(text, cleaned_codebook_list) {
  
  max_matches <- 0
  max_list_name <- NULL
  matched_phrases <- character()
  
  for (list_name in names(cleaned_codebook_list)) {
    codebook_phrases <- cleaned_codebook_list[[list_name]]
    matches <- sum(sapply(codebook_phrases, function(phrase) grepl(phrase, text)))
    
    if (matches > max_matches) {
      max_matches <- matches
      max_list_name <- list_name
      matched_phrases <- codebook_phrases[sapply(codebook_phrases, function(phrase) grepl(phrase, text))]
    }
  }
  
  return(list(max_list_name = max_list_name, matched_phrases = matched_phrases))
  
}

#Applying the function to each row in df_text
result <- apply(df_text, 1, function(row) {
  find_max_matching_list(row["Text"], cleaned_codebook_list)
})

# Assigning results to the dataframe
df_text$charging_type <- sapply(result, function(res) res$max_list_name)
df_text$matched_words <- sapply(result, function(res) paste(res$matched_phrases, collapse = ", "))
```

Answer (score 1):

you asked the same question yesterday and I answered your question with an easy to understand and reproducible example - such examples are beneficial as other people can often more easily transfer coding approaches to their field/use case. However, it seems that you have deleted that question, and thus the answer, and are looking for code that uses the exact data you provided. So I'll give you the same answer here as yesterday, this time using your data. If it does not the job for you, please explain.

```
library(tidyverse)

## data below

lookup_private <- paste(
  c("income tax credit", "property owners", "homeowner", "owner", "personal use",
    "condominium", "common interest",  "housing association", "tenant", 
    "residential", "residents", "purchasers"),
  collapse = "|"
)

lookup_commercial <- paste(
  c("commercial", "fleet", "nonprofit","non-residential", "industrial"),
  collapse = "|"
)

lookup_public <- paste(
  c("public", "utility-owned", "fast charging", "interstates", "highways", 
    "network", "general public", "operators", "operator", "IOUs", 
    "infrastructure", "disadvantaged communities", 
    "charging station service providers", "low-income", "underserved"),
  collapse = "|"
)

dat %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    charging_type = paste(c(
      if(grepl(lookup_private, v1)){"private"},
      if(grepl(lookup_commercial, v1)){"commercial"},
      if(grepl(lookup_public, v1)){"public"}
    ),
    collapse= ", ")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(charging_type = na_if(charging_type, ""))
```

data (that you provided; maybe `v1` needs some cleaning before, e.g., many empty spaces)

```
dat <- tibble(
  manual_classification = c(
    "private", NA, "public", "public", "?", NA, "private", "public",
    "commercial", NA, "public", NA, NA, "private", NA),
  v1 = c(
    "a common interest development  including a community apartment \ncondominium and cooperative development  may not prohibit or restrict\nthe installation or use of ev charging stations or ev dedicated\ntime of use  tou  meter in a homeowner s designated parking space or\nunit  these entities may put reasonable restrictions on ev charging\nstations  but the policies may not significantly increase the cost of\nthe ev charging stations or significantly decrease its efficiency or\nperformance  restrictions may be placed on tou meter installations if\nthey are based on the structure of or available space in the building \nif installation in the homeowner s designated parking space or unit is\nnot possible  with authorization  the homeowner may add ev charging\nstations or a ev dedicated tou meter in a common area  the homeowner\nmust obtain appropriate approvals from the common interest development\nassociation and agree in writing to comply with applicable architectural\nstandards  engage a licensed installation contractor  provide a\ncertificate of insurance  and pay for the electricity usage \nmaintenance  and other costs associated with the ev charging stations or\ntou meter  any application for approval should be processed by the\ncommon interest development association without willful avoidance or\ndelay  the homeowner and each successive homeowner of the parking space\nor unit equipped with ev charging stations or a tou meter is responsible\nfor the cost of the installation  maintenance  repair  removal  or\nreplacement of the equipment  as well as any resulting damage to the ev\ncharging stations  tou meter  or surrounding area  the homeowner must\nalso maintain a   1 million umbrella liability coverage policy and name\nthe common interest development as an additional insured entity under\nthe policy  if ev charging stations or an ev dedicated tou meter is\ninstalled in a common area for use by all members of the association \nthe common interest development must develop terms for use of the ev\ncharging stations or tou meter \n reference  california civil code 4745 and 6713  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
     "the san joaquin valley air pollution control district  sjvapcd  and thesouth coast air quality management district  aqmd  administer enhancedfleet modernization program  efmp  pilot retire and replace programs providing incentives to replace a vehicle eligible for retirement with amore fuel efficient vehicle  used vehicles must be no more than eightyears old and applicants must live in the san joaquin valley or southcoast air basins  eligible replacement vehicles must meet a minimum fueleconomy average by model year or average at least 35 miles per gallon mpg   alternative fuel vehicles are also eligible  including plug inhybrid electric vehicles  phev  and battery electric vehicles  evs  funding for alternative transportation mobility options  such as publictransportation or car sharing  is also available in lieu of purchasinganother vehicle  the incentive amounts vary by income level as comparedto the federal poverty level  fpl  and replacement vehicle type  alleligible applicants must have a household income that is at or below400  of the fpl      data align  center    income eligibility                    fuel economy greater than 35 mpg   phev or zev                                                                                         low income    225  fpl                              4 500                    4 500  moderate income    300  fpl                         3 500                    3 500  above moderate income    400  fpl                   2 500                    2 500   residents living in qualified disadvantaged communities may be eligiblefor higher incentive amounts and  for residents replacing their vehicleswith a phev or ev  a rebate of up to   2 000 for the purchase ofelectric vehicle supply equipment  residents of south coast aqmd mayalso be eligible to receive a rebate of   7 500 for alternativetransportation mobility options  for more information  includingeligible vehicles and applicable requirements  see the california airresources board efmp  https   ww2 arb ca gov our work programs enhanced fleet modernization program  sjvapcd  driveclean  https   www valleyair org drivecleaninthesanjoaquin replace   and south coast aqmd  replace yourride  http   www replaceyourride com   websites  reference  california health and safety code 44062 3 and 44125  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
     "municipalities may not restrict the types of evs  such as plug in hybridelectric vehicles  that may access an ev charging station that ispublic  intended for passenger vehicle use  and funded in any part bythe state or utility ratepayers  reference  california government code 65850 9  http   www oal ca gov   ", 
     "the washington state department of ecology  ecology  will work with the\noffice of the governor and state agencies to select projects and\ndistribute funding to leverage 15  of washington  s portion of the  vw\nenvironmental mitigation\ntrust  https   www epa gov enforcement volkswagen clean air act civil settlement \nfor the acquisition  installation  operation  and maintenance of\nlight duty zero emission vehicle charging infrastructure \necology will establish a competitive process to identify and select\nprojects to fund with the remaining 85  of the appropriation to maximize\ntotal air pollution reduction and health benefits  improve air quality\nin areas disproportionately affected by air pollution  leverage\nadditional matching funds  achieve substantial emission reduction beyond\nwhat would occur absent the funding  accelerate fleet turnover to the\ncleanest engines  and accelerate adoption of electric vehicles \nequipment  and vessels  as appropriate  ecology will work with state\nagencies to select projects and distribute funding  for more\ninformation  see the ecology  vw enforcement\naction  https   ecology wa gov about us how we operate grants loans find a grant or loan volkswagen enforcement action grants \nwebsite \n", 
     "an individual may not park a motor vehicle within any parking space\nspecifically designated for charging evs  to use the parking space  evs\nmust be actively charging  violators may receive a fine of up to   750 \n reference  nevada revised statutes 484b 468  https   www leg state nv us   ", 
     "by january 1  2026  the kentucky finance and administration cabinet\n cabinet  must increase the use of ethanol  biodiesel  and other\nalternative transportation fuels and replace at least 50  of light duty\nstate fleet vehicles with new alternative fuel vehicles or vehicles\nequipped with low emission technology  beginning december 1  2024  the\ncabinet must compile annual reports detailing the progress made towards\nthese requirements  including a life cycle cost assessment  vehicle\nreplacement timeline  and targets for increased alternative fuels in\nstate agency vehicles \n\n reference  senate bill 281  2023  https   legislature ky gov legislation pages default aspx    26 u s  code 30b  http   www gpo gov fdsys    and  kentucky revised statutes 45a 625 and 152 715  http   lrc ky gov krs titles htm  ", 
     "an income tax credit is available for 50  of the cost of alternative\nfueling infrastructure  up to   5 000  qualifying infrastructure\nincludes electric vehicle charging stations and equipment to dispense\nfuel that is 85  or more natural gas  propane  or hydrogen  unused\ncredits may be carried over into future tax years  for more information \nincluding how to claim the credit  please see the new york state\n department of taxation and\nfinance  http   www tax ny gov pit credits alt fuels elec vehicles htm \nwebsite   reference  new york tax\nlaw  http   public leginfo state ny us lawssrch cgi nvlwo   187 b ", 
     "tva will establish and fund a network of direct current fast charging\n dcfc  stations every 50 miles along interstates and major highways\nthrough the fast charge network program  program   the program offers\nfunding for public dcfc stations along ev corridor gaps  up to   150 000\nper dcfc station  eligible applicants include tva local power companies \nand eligible projects must include a minimum of two dcfc ports per\nlocation  program participants must identify suitable host sites and\nagree to own  operate  and maintain program funded dcfc stations for a\nminimum of five years  for more information  including guidelines and\nadditional eligibility requirements  see the tva  fast charge\nnetwork  https   energyright com ev fast charger program   website \n", 
     "pwp offers rebates of   3 000 per port for commercial  workplace multi unit dwelling  mud   and fleet customers for the installation ofnetworked level 2 ev charging stations  or rebates of   1 500 per portfor non networked level 2 ev charging stations  pwp also offers rebatesof   6 000 for the installation of direct current fast charging  dcfc stations or level 2 ev charging stations installed at select sites including disadvantaged communities  additional terms and conditionsapply  for more information  including how to apply  see the pwp commercial ev and charger incentiveprogram  https   ww5 cityofpasadena net water and power commercialchargerrebate  website ", 
     "the u s  department of transportation s  dot   nevi formulaprogram  https   afdc energy gov laws 12744  requires the alabamadepartment of transportation  aldot   to submit an annual evinfrastructure deployment plan  plan  to the dot and u s  department ofenergy  doe   joint office of energy andtransportation  https   driveelectric gov   joint office   describinghow the state intends to distribute nevi funds  the submitted plans mustbe established according to  neviguidance  https   www fhwa dot gov environment alternative fuel corridors nominations 90d nevi formula program guidance pdf  for more information about alabama s nevi planning process  see thealabama department of economic and community affairs  electric vehiclecharging infrastructure program  https   adeca alabama gov ev   website to review alabama s nevi plan  see the joint office  state plans for evcharging  https   driveelectric gov state plans   website ", 
     "at least one parking space  or 10  of parking spaces rounded to the next\nwhole number  must be made ready for level 2 ev charging stations at all\nnew buildings  electrical capacity must accommodate the potential to\nserve a minimum of 20  of the total parking spaces with level 2 ev\ncharging stations  for assembly  education  or mercantile buildings  the\nrequirements apply only to employee parking spaces  buildings classified\nas utility or miscellaneous and some residential buildings are exempt\nfrom these requirements  additional terms and conditions apply \n reference  revised code of washington 51 50 0429  https   apps leg wa gov rcw   ", 
     "cities and counties that receive funding from the road maintenance andrehabilitation program are encouraged to use funds towards advancedtransportation technologies and communication systems  including  butnot limited to  zero emission vehicle fueling infrastructure andinfrastructure to vehicle communications for autonomous vehicles  reference  california streets and highways code 2030  http   leginfo legislature ca gov faces home xhtml  ", 
     NA,
    "homeowners associations  hoas  or condominium associations may not\nprohibit the installation of an ev charging station for personal use\nwithin the ev charging station owner s designated parking space  hoas\nmay establish restrictions on the number  size  placement  manner of\ninstallation  and insurance requirements for the ev charging station if\nit is installed on the exterior of the property or in a common area \nhoas are not liable for the ev charging station \na condominium association may prohibit the installation of an ev\ncharging station if it is not technically feasible or practical due to\nsafety risks  structural issues  or engineering conditions  condominiums\nmay establish requirements on the manner of installation  architectural\ndesign  insurance requirements  and community related expenses for the\nev charging station \n reference  virginia code 55 1 1823 1  55 1 1962 1  and 55 1 2139 1  https   law lis virginia gov vacode   ", 
     "new evs must be equipped with a conductive charger inlet port that meetsthe specifications contained in society of automotive engineers  sae standard j1772  evs must be equipped with an on board charger with aminimum output of 3 3 kilowatts  kw   these requirements do not apply toevs that are only capable of level 1 charging  which has a maximum powerof 12 amperes  amps   a branch circuit rating of 15 amps  and continuouspower of 1 44 kw  reference  california code of regulations title 13  section 1962 2  http   www oal ca gov   "
    ), 
  charging_type = NA
  )
```

Comment: This works. Thank you so much! (I deleted the previous question because I thought it wasn't clear enough - thank you for answering again!) :)